# How does barrier function method for semidefinite programming avoid the case when even eigenvalues are negative?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

Log-barrier function adds the expression $-\log(\det X)$ to the objective function to ensure that the matrix $X$ is positive definite.But when even eigenvalues of X is negative this expression is still finite.How does barrier function method avoid this?

Comment: In interior point methods, we start inside the feasibility set and at each iteration we remain in the feasibility set. If we approach the boundary of the feasibility set, the barrier function increases and is equal to infinity on the boundary. We never crosses the boundary. So, no eigenvalue of $X$ will get negative (or even zero).

Comment: @KBS: This is not entirely true. You start in an interior point, but the suggested step (from steepest descent / Newton / whatever) might be big and it might just happen that you land in a point with, e.g., $2$ negative eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that you need the "correct" definition of log-det:
$$
-\operatorname{log\,det}X :=
\begin{cases}
-\log(\det(X)) & \text{if } X \succeq 0 \\
+\infty & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Also note that the function defined via
$$
f(X) :=
\begin{cases}
-\log(\det(X)) & \text{if } \det(X) \ge 0 \\
+\infty & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
fails to be convex (in dimensions at least $2$).

Comment: Then how to avoid reaching a solution with 2 negative eigenvalues?

Comment: By defining $-\log\det X := +\infty$ whenever $X$ is not positive semi-definite.

Comment: In that case,we have to check whether X is positive semi-definite every time we get a solution.So what is its advantage over simply using the indicator function?

Comment: The advantage is that $\log\det$ is a barrier functional, i.e., it goes to $\infty$ if you approach the boundary of the feasible set.